# Asp.net mvc Razor view - Telerik().DateTimePicker() inside Telerik().TabStrip() gives JS error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, datetimepicker

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code in the main view, lets say Account/Index.cshtml

```
@( Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
           .Name("TabStrip")
            .Effects(fx => fx.Expand()
                            .Opacity()
                            .OpenDuration(200)
                            .CloseDuration(300))
           .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "width:800px;" })
           .SelectedIndex(0)
           .Items(parent => {
                parent.Add()
                    .Text("Article")
                    .LoadContentFrom("ChangePassword", "Account");
                parent.Add()
                    .Text("Users")
                    .LoadContentFrom("_Register", "Account");
                })
    )
```

In the "_Register" view, i have the below

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
       .Name("DatePickerAttributes.SelectedDate")
       .Value(DateTime.Today)
  )
```

It seems that, in IE, it throws an error and Calendar is not at all opening. 
But if i add the below manually, even though JS error, the calendar opens

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#DatePickerAttributes_SelectedDate').tDatePicker({ format: 'M/d/yyyy', minValue: new Date(1899, 11, 31), maxValue: new Date(2100, 00, 01), selectedValue: new Date(2011, 06, 09) });
    });
```

Note: If firefox, it works great without any error.

Hope that, in IE, `LoadContentFrom("_Register", "Account");` not loads the view completely, but fine in FireFox.

Comment: `Any help would be appreciated!`. That's your question? No relevant source code to show? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the Required JavaScript files by the DatePicker registered? You need to do so for components loaded on demand via LoadContentFrom. The [troubleshooting](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-troubleshooting.html#LoadOnDemand) help article show how.

Comment: Thanks Atanas, for your nice pointer.

You are right! I haven't added the below 2 manually.
telerik.calendar.min.js
telerik.datepicker.min.js

Thanks a lot!